How to use **kwargs with MyPy
Consider the following code, which I would like to type-check:
def foo(add_count: bool = False) -> int:
    return 5 if add_count else 0


def A(x: int, y: int, **kwargs: dict) -> int:
    return x + y + foo(**kwargs)


def B(a: int, b: int, **kwargs: dict) -> int:
    return a - b + foo(**kwargs)


def C(s: int, t: int, **kwargs: dict) -> int:
    return A(s, t, **kwargs) + B(s, t, **kwargs)

mypy complains about this pattern:
typing.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "**dict[str, dict[Any, Any]]"; expected "bool"  [arg-type]
typing.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "**dict[str, dict[Any, Any]]"; expected "bool"  [arg-type]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

But I think this code is perfectly fine. It allows for passing keyword arguments to inner functions (foo):
C(5, 6, add_count=True)
# 20 

While still catching invalid or unknown keyword arguments:
C(5, 6, add_num=1)
# TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'add_num'

Coming from an R background, I use this pattern often in situations where the functions I wrote (A, B, and C) are wrapping/calling some external library function foo which itself has many parameters (e.g. 30+).
I've read the solution proposed e.g. here and here, but I consider it unacceptable as it adds far too much complexity to an existing codebase; why should I have to design a TypedDict for the parameters of an external library function foo?
I can't help but think I'm missing something. What's the recommended best practice here?

Edit:
This question has been marked as a duplicate of this question, which I'm actually not sure if the solution is contained somewhere in that thread and it's associated references (it is not so far as I can tell).
The second answer to the linked 'duplicate' answer is close to what I think the solution is. It proposes to use the Unpack construction; Let me amend my example above with what I thought would work:
from typing import Unpack, TypedDict 

Params = TypedDict("Params", {}, total=False)

def A(x: int, y: int, **kwargs: Unpack[Params]) -> int: ...
def B(a: int, b: int, **kwargs: Unpack[Params]) -> int: ...
def C(s: int, t: int, **kwargs: Unpack[Params]) -> int: ...

I thought I could use this to encompass arbitrary types, as total=False indicates the dictionary need not be complete. But this fails to type check, even though the runtime is fine:
C(1, 5, add_count=True) # error: Unexpected keyword argument "add_count" for "C"  [call-arg]


kwargs is a dict, not bool, so, I’m not sure why you expect any other outcome than you’re seeing.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/839733

I guess semantically I'm trying to achieve something more like **kwargs: Unpack[dict]

I assumed so, but kwargs is special. You can unpack a regular dict using ** (called the splat operator). One thing you could try is first saving the **kwargs to a regular dict, and then splat it, although I don’t know if that trick will work.

@InSync I don’t think this question is a dup of the one you linked to. OP is trying to splat the kwargs as a regular dict, the values being passed as named arguments. It really has very little to do with typing, although it may seem so on the surface.

@AbhijitSarkar This one, then: Annotate function that passes parameters to another function. This question is exclusively about typing, as I see it, because OP said "[...] which I would like to type-check".

@InSync I've updated my question with a counter example to the (second) answer of the proposed duplicate question. The first answer is far too narrow for me: using kwargs: bool implies all keyword arguments will be bool, which may not be true.
@AbhijitSarkar yes this is about typing, I'm aware of how the unpacking operator works.

Edit 2: actually the second link "Annotate function that passes parameters to another function" seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks @InSync

Edit 3: I flagged my question as duplicate of the this question, which answers my question.
